# Xamarin.Forms Page with a AbsoluteLayout at the top and CarouselPage below

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm just starting with Xamarin, and would like to get the following layout, but can't seem to implement it:

[image: Layout]

I would like to keep the top menu bar (Not a toolbar or navigationbar) static at all times, so that it won't move when the CarouselPage changes navigation. I like the CarouselPage for its builtin swiping and navigation properties. It would be like the NavigationPage, only I would like to controll the whole bar on top, without any restrictions to the content (You can only add a button, right?)

Can anyone give me some advice on how to get this working?

Comment: There's a feature request right now for a CarouselView.  So at the minute you can't have that exact setup.

Answer (score 1):

`CarouselPage` is a `Page`, which basically can't be part of a `Layout` but only a top-level element.

Answer (score 0):

Now it is possible to use `CarouselView` which overcomes the 'can not be part of a `Layout`' restriction of `CarouselPage`, and can be embedded easily inside a `AbsoluteLayout` or any other layout.

More details regarding this control can be found [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/).